# How can I style the WYSIWYG content?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Let's say I'm currently editing a page and there is a WYSIWYG editor in the backend to edit a specific part.

Now I add a table via the WYSIWYG. How can I apply CSS styles on that table WITHOUT altering the CKEditor plugin settings (I don't want to provide classes in the "Styles" dropdown)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either implement [hook_ckeditor_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21ckeditor.api.php/function/hook_ckeditor_css_alter/8.2.x) or you can add `ckeditor_stylesheets` to your themes info.yml file.

See: [hook_ckeditor_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21ckeditor.api.php/function/hook_ckeditor_css_alter/8.2.x) for more.

Example:

```
function mymodule_ckeditor_css_alter(array &$css, Editor $editor) {
  $css[] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/css/mymodule-ckeditor.css';
}
```

Or in mytheme.info.yml:

```
ckeditor_stylesheets:
  - css/styles.css
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited the mytheme.info.yml as you suggested and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by flipping to HTML source, and adding a class in the html.

Perhaps this is for a user that you do not want to give privileged permissions to? (which I assume would include 'Source' button on a WYSIWYG)

If so maybe you can generally style a table in a nice way (ie not need a class or inline styling) or perhaps target the area that this table will be displaying, if its a particular node type you could target that existing class and style the table beneath that:

```
.custom_content_type table {
  /* Your styles here*/
}
```